# Position from distance from three vertices of a triangle

Tags: geometry

I have a magnetometer sensor on each vertices of an isosceles triangle. I also have a magnet that can be anywhere on the triangle (inside, on edges, etc). I have the magnitude reading from each sensor (essentially giving me the distance the magnet is from each vertices of the triangle). I'd like to calculate the x,y coordinates from these three distances.

The magnet can be assumed to always be inside the triangle (or on it's borders).

How would I calculate this?

Comment: Is the magnet assumed inside the closure of the triangle?

Comment: Spencer-- I still would like the answer to my comment question. If you aren't allowed to comment yet you could edit your question and put that detail in it.

Comment: @coffeemath He should edit the question and put the details in and not hide them ín comments.

Comment: If you’re dealing with real-life noisy data, be prepared to deal with the resulting equations being inconsistent.

Comment: Updated... yes the magnet will be within the triangle. I'd like to use three sensors to improve the accuracy.

Comment: How is this off topic. The help center says: "This question does not appear to be about math." Really? Maybe they should read the answers to the question to see if there is any math in there.

Answer (score 1):

In theory, you just compute the common intersection of three circles. In practice, noisy real-world data make it likely that the resulting system of equations is inconsistent: the three measured circles don’t have a common intersection point. You will in all likelihood need to find an approximate solution.

A fairly inexpensive approximation uses a method by which the intersection might be computed in the ideal case, anyway: the pairwise radical axes of any set of three circles are guaranteed to be coincident. This point is known as the *radical center* of the configuration. When two circles intersect, their radical axis is the secant line through the intersection points, an equation for which can be found by subtracting one circle equation from the other. Thus, you compute the intersection of three lines with equations of the form $$2(x_j-x_i)x+2(y_j-y_i)y+(x_i^2+y_i^2-r_i^2)-(x_j^2+y_j^2-r_j^2)=0.$$ Since you know that the three lines are coincident, you can simply compute the intersection of any two of them, which can be done in homogeneous coordinates with a cross product. Once again, truncation and other errors can make the full three-equation system inconsistent, so if you’re being extra paranoid, compute a least-squares solution to it. Indeed, if you’re going to be doing a lot of measurements relative to static sensor configuration, you can precompute most of the latter solution so that computing each location requires at most squaring the three distances, a matrix-vector multiplication and a vector addition.

Comment: This is great. Thanks for taking the time to answer. Yes, I believe taking a least-squares approach would be best. When you say "if you’re going to be doing a lot of measurements relative to static sensor configuration, you can precompute most of the latter' what exactly am I pre-computing?

Comment: @SpencerClegg The least-squares solution to the system $A\mathbf x=\mathbf b$ is $\mathbf x = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf b$. Obviously, you can precompute the pseudoinverse $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$, but in this problem you can decompose $\mathbf b$ into the sum of a static vector $\mathbf s$ that depends only on the sensor positions and a vector $\mathbf r$ that depends only on the measurements. You can then also precompute $\mathbf s$ or even $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T\mathbf s$.

Comment: @SpencerClegg On the other hand, matrix inversion is notoriously unstable, so you might be better off precomputing $A^T$, $A^TA$ and $A^T\mathbf s$, say, and then computing the solution to $A^TA\mathbf x=A^T\mathbf r+A^T\mathbf s$ some other way, such as Gaussian elimination.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume the magnet inside the closure of the triangle. It can be done using only two of the distances, if things are set up right. After a translation and a rotation, we may assume $A=(0,0),B=(0,c),$ and $C=(c_1,c_2)$ where $c_2>0.$ Here $c$ is the length of the side opposite $C.$

Now let $P=(x,y)$ be the point in the triangle to be found, so we have $y \ge 0.$ Also let $s=d(A,P),t=d(B,P).$ Then we have
$$ x^2+y^2=s^2, \\  (c-x)^2 + y^2=t^2.$$
Subtracting gives $c^2-2cx=t^2-s^2,$ from which $x$ follows. Putting this into $x^2+y^2=s^2$ now gives $y,$ since $y \ge 0.$

Added: To address miracle's (correct) comment-- If $P$ is not assumed to be inside the triangle, one does need the third distance: Do as above. and after getting $y^2$ there are two possible points depending on the sign of $y.$ See which it is by checking the distance $d(P,C).$

Comment: I think there is a good reason why one uses three sensors  and not only two. Your answer ignores this.

Comment: @miracle173 Thanks, see recent edit.